# codeigniter routes not working without index.php in live server inside default var/www/html folder

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Codeigniter routes works in local server. when I deploy to `var/www/html` of server, the routes not working as expected.

when I add `index.php` before controller name in URL, it works fine.

but without `index.php`, it throws 404 page not found error

`.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I tried this as well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /var/www/html/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but nothing works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like mod_rewrite is not enabled in your server.
If the rewrite rule isn't working, ensure you are allowing .htaccess files in your Apache config file. The directory section should contain an AllowOverride All option:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Don't forget that any changes to the Apache config file require a service restart!

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

go to application\config\config.php file

**Make changes**

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /YourCIFolderName/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /YourCIFolderName/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: not working. i tried all. is there anything to change? this problem happens only on ubuntu server

Comment: may I know url of your controller? Means where you install CI

Comment: @NithinM please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1

go to application/config/config.php
find

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
change it to
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**STEP 2**

go to application/config/routes.php

remove everything from the bottom of the page after the comment ends and paste below code

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main'; // main is your default controller name
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
$route['admin'] = 'admin/login';
```

**STEP 3**

add a new file named as .htaccess in the root folder where you have the folders named application and system etc

add the below code and open the website

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```